# Knockout textInput binding not updating value

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using google maps places api to auto-complete search input value.

```
<input data-bind="textInput: searchInput" id="location" type="text">
```

So when I start typing in the input box, for example I type `Ro` and then from the auto-complete suggestion I select `Rome` and click submit, the value of `searchInput()` still is set to `Ro` instead of `Rome`.
How may I get the `searchInput()` to update after selecting an auto-complete suggestion?

Comment: where is the autocomplete control, can you post that code too ? You can try to use select2. https://select2.github.io/

Comment: it is a google maps places api feature, `var locationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('location'));`

Comment: In that case, you can set the value for searchInput variable from JS code. I beleive locationAutocomplete should provide you with the value selected in the auto completion.

Comment: Yes, I can do that but I am trying to do it with knockout.

Comment: the variable searchInput is observable, Knockout allows the value of any observable to be set in JS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps fires a `place_changed` event when selecting from the auto-complete. You can catch that event and fire an `input` event on the element that Knockout can read:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    ko.utils.triggerEvent(input, "input");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dxdyqbxr/

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used knockout but inside your ViewModel where you defined your searchInput you would create a computedFunction.  When your value changes in the textbox it would fire off the auto complete feature and when the value is chosen it would update the searchInput which would update your textbox.  Not sure if an infinite loop could exist here so be sure to test and tweak.

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  self.searchInput('autocompleteValue');
});

self.UseAutoComplete = ko.computedFunction((
  google.maps.places.Autocomplete(self.searchInput());
));
```